# list format for popen streamlink

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to run subprocess.popen with out the Shell=true, but can't figure out how to format my list. it will always fail with an invalid url or 403. Like it doesn't set the cookie or header.

Example url

```
https://vodus-i-video-xxx.xxx.net/vodus/1d9cfcbc-8469-4c9f-b44a-6412091b733d/NoADs_IND_SEA_720_pre1.ism/QualityLevels(4740905)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl-v3,audiotrack=aac_UND_2_127,filter=chromecast)?hdnea=st=1535729260~exp=1535729440~acl=/*~hmac=977cba9e480bcdb7b89033488f37679b4a6906f8f7a981a055b88a0802012c71&hdcore=2.11.3|Connection=keep-alive&User-Agent=Firefox|Connection=keep-alive&User-Agent=Firefox
```

I parse the url to get the cookie::

```
"hdnea=st=1535729260~exp=1535729440~acl=/*~hmac=977cba9e480bcdb7b89033488f37679b4a6906f8f7a981a055b88a0802012c71&hdcore=2.11.3;path=/; domain=livemain-i-video-xxx.xxx.net;86400s"
```

final string which will work with Shell=true

```
streamlink --player-external-http --player-external-http-port 10000 --http-header "User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0" --http-cookie "hdnea=st=1535729260~exp=1535729440~acl=/*~hmac=977cba9e480bcdb7b89033488f37679b4a6906f8f7a981a055b88a0802012c71&hdcore=2.11.3;path=/; domain=livemain-i-video-xxx.xxx.net;86400s" "hlsvariant://https://vodus-i-video-xxx.xxx.net/vodus/1d9cfcbc-8469-4c9f-b44a-6412091b733d/NoADs_IND_SEA_720_pre1.ism/QualityLevels(4740905)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl-v3,audiotrack=aac_UND_2_127,filter=chromecast)?hdnea=st=1535729260~exp=1535729440~acl=/*~hmac=977cba9e480bcdb7b89033488f37679b4a6906f8f7a981a055b88a0802012c71&hdcore=2.11.3|Connection=keep-alive&User-Agent=Firefox|Connection=keep-alive&User-Agent=Firefox" best
```

This is how I tried to format but just can't seem to get it right.

```
stream_url="https://vodus-i-video-nfl.akamaized.net/vodus/1d9cfcbc-8469-4c9f-b44a-6412091b733d/NoADs_IND_SEA_720_pre1.ism/QualityLevels(4740905)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl-v3,audiotrack=aac_UND_2_127,filter=chromecast)?hdnea=st=1535729260~exp=1535729440~acl=/*~hmac=977cba9e480bcdb7b89033488f37679b4a6906f8f7a981a055b88a0802012c71&hdcore=2.11.3|Connection=keep-alive&User-Agent=Firefox|Connection=keep-alive&User-Agent=Firefox"
urlsplit = stream_url.split('?')
getcookie = urlsplit[1].split('|')
cookie = getcookie[0] 
cmd = [
"streamlink",
"--player-external-http",
"--player-external-http-port", 
"%s" %(port),
"--http-header",
"\"User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0\"",
"--http-cookie",
"\"%s" %(cookie) + ";path=/;domain=livemain-i-video-nfl.akamaized.net;86400s\"",
"%s" %(streamtest),   
"best"
]
    logger.info("Running cmd: %s" % " ".join(cmd))
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, err = proc.communicate()
    logging.info(output)
```

Output i get is:

> INFO:root:Running cmd: streamlink --player-external-http --player-external-http-port 15000 --http-header "User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0" --http-cookie "hdnea=st=1535680989~exp=1535681169~acl=/*~hmac=0232a24cb481541387ff7984e7b78f44f6ccdf3d2893d8bbbe4eb7e44fe1baea&hdcore=2.11.3;path=/;domain=livemain-i-video-xxx.xxx.net;86400s" hlsvariant://https://livemain-i-video-xxx.xxx.net/ch16/7fd8a3f6-5dee-4ed1-b23f-7398684ff5bd/7fd8a3f6-5dee-4ed1-b23f-7398684ff5bd.ism/QualityLevels(2200000)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl-v3,audiotrack=audio,filter=chromecast-live) best
>
> INFO:root:[cli][info] streamlink is running as root! Be careful!
>   [cli][info] Found matching plugin hls for URL hlsvariant://https://livemain-i-video-xxx.xxx.net/ch16/7fd8a3f6-5dee-4ed1-b23f-7398684ff5bd/7fd8a3f6-5dee-4ed1-b23f-7398684ff5bd.ism/QualityLevels(2200000)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl-v3,audiotrack=audio,filter=chromecast-live)
>   error: Unable to open URL: https://livemain-i-video-xxx.xxx.net/ch16/7fd8a3f6-5dee-4ed1-b23f-7398684ff5bd/7fd8a3f6-5dee-4ed1-b23f-7398684ff5bd.ism/QualityLevels(2200000)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl-v3,audiotrack=audio,filter=chromecast-live) (403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://livemain-i-video-xxx.xxx.net/ch16/7fd8a3f6-5dee-4ed1-b23f-7398684ff5bd/7fd8a3f6-5dee-4ed1-b23f-7398684ff5bd.ism/QualityLevels(2200000)/Manifest(video,format=m3u8-aapl-v3,audiotrack=audio,filter=chromecast-live))

What the join does looks correct, but just can't seem to get it right. I do think I need the double quotes for the cookie and url because of the special characters. Was just hoping to get an output and with Shell=True you don't get an output until its finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The literal quotes around the User-Agent header and the cookie look suspicious.  I would guess you want

```
cmd = [
    "streamlink",
    "--player-external-http",
    "--player-external-http-port", 
    str(port),
    "--http-header",
    "User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0",
    "--http-cookie",
    "%s;path=/;domain=livemain-i-video-nfl.akamaized.net;86400s"%(cookie),
    streamtest,
    "best"
]
```

Notice also how we avoid using `%` string formatting to turn something into a string which already *is* a string.